# iPhone Video Rotationn

Tags: iphone

I'm using the UIIMagePickerController for video capture but after the capture I publish it on our servers and it turns out that the video is not properly oriented. But this problem only occurs when the user take's video in Portrait mode in LandScape Mode everything is simply fine.

Is there any way in which I can detect in which mode video was captured and How can i rotate the video before publish so that everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can query the `UIDevice` for `@property UIDeviceOrientation orientation`, and let the server know if the video was captured in landscape or portrait.

You can use one of the helpful [UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW37) macro to do this.

To query for current orientation, just do

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

but watch out: (from UIDevice documentation) The value of this property always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.

Comment: I can't point you to a way of rotating the video on the device. However, from my experience with iPhone devices, rotating it on the device should not be done due to performance constraints. The server would be a better place to do this, IMHO.

Comment: Please just this Last one can I set the Orientation of the UIImagePickerController to a default Landscape Mode so that My issue is inherently resolved on its own.

Comment: According to UIImagePickerController documentation, you cannot change the mode, or subclass the picker to force it to be shown in landscape only: 

"The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing." 

However, maybe you should investigate into why the problem occurs in landscape? Does the received video really have 'portrait orientation' (i.e. the frame width is less than the frame height?)

Comment: Yes, the frame width is less than the frame height and Landscaped video is Proper. I'm really stuck at this silly issue.

Comment: You could try and make your root UIViewController be rotatable to landscape only - try to override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in your controller. 

Also see http://bit.ly/6ImFp0 - maybe your applications should be landscape-only?